NTFS - INDEX_ROOT and $SDH
I'm trying to write a program that can read an NTFS filesystem from binary. However, I've run into an issue with trying to understand the INDEX_ROOT attribute in a file record. Specifically, I'm trying to figure out how the $SDH stream in $Secure works. Specifically, I have the following questions:

What is the actual index entry field in an INDEX_ROOT attribute? It seems like it should simply contain the data for exactly the index entry, but I can't tell if that's actually what it contains or if it simply points to the index entry's data. The attribute is resident, from what I can tell, so that isn't the problem.

Does $SDH in particular have any unique storage aspects (i.e. fields being used for a different purpose than in a normal index entry), or do all of the index entries point to a file which contains the data stream?


Tried reading the documentation, results were unclear. I've mostly been following this site:
https://flatcap.github.io/linux-ntfs/ntfs/attributes/index.html
It's possible that I just missed something in here, but I don't think I have.
